# MongoNetworkError when saving 20 000 documents in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to save 20 00 documents in mongo db using Mongoose. I get this error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out

I dont get this error when i save only one document.

Here is my code :

```
collections.forEach(product =>{
 saveProduct(product)
 .then(p=> console.log(p.keyword))
 .catch(err=>console.log(err));
})

export function saveProduct(pro):Promise<any>{
let proSave = new Product(pro);
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    proSave.save(function(err,prox){
        if(err){
            reject(err);
        }else{
            resolve(proSave)
        }
    })
})}
```

Please any idea

Thank

Comment: In short there's a number of things you are doing wrong here, but to give others a clearer idea you could explain what `collections` actually is. Is it an "array" of data already loaded? Does it possibly come from another source if it is? Or is it something else similar like another database source to be iterated? You're big problem is that you have defined no governance at all over how many operations are "in flight" at any particular time, and this will cause issues. It's completely avoidable, but it's best to understand what you are actually doing in order to advise the best action.

Comment: Hi. The collections is array of documents loaded from xml file. What do you mean ' you have defined no governance at all over how many operations are "in flight" ' ?

Answer (score 0):

Newbies and developers working on data with coordinates might experience this issues. If you are having any issues relating to the topic above. You have to visit the Mongodb website https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries on latest update.